# Converting a C byte array to a long long

Tags: c, arrays, byte, long-integer

I have an 8-byte array in my application with this data:

```
00000133339e36a2
```

This data represents a long (on the platform the data was written in, on a Mac this would be a long long) with the value of

```
1319420966562
```

In the actual application this is a semi-randomized set of data, so the number will always be different. Therefore, I need to convert the byte array into a printable long long.

I've tried casting the data directly into a long long, but I came up with

```
1305392
```

where I should have been seeing the above number.

For those of you with more experience in C byte manipulation than I do, how would I correctly convert a byte array to a long long?

EDIT: Strangely, all of your solutions keep outputting the same number: 866006690. That is the decimal equivalent of the *last four* bytes of the data.

Answer (score 6):

This seems one of the (rare) situations where an union is useful:

```
union number
{
    char charNum[16];
    long long longNum;
};
```

Comment: Excellent solution, haven't thought of that.

Answer (score 4):

```
union le_long_long_array_u
{
  uint8_t byte[8];
  uint64_t longlong;
} le_long_long_array;
```

Copy (or just use) `le_long_long_array.byte[]` for the array;
 read back `le_long_long_array.longlong`

For example:

```
fill_array(&le_long_long_array.byte[0]);
return le_long_long_array.longlong;
```

Fuller example:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

union le_long_long_array_u
{
  uint8_t byte[8];
  uint64_t longlong;
} le_long_long_array;

static uint8_t hex2int (char c)
{
    return (c >= '0' && c <= '9') 
            ? (uint8_t )(c  - '0')
            : ((c >= 'a' && c <= 'f') 
                ? (uint8_t )(c  - 'a')
                : ((c >= 'A' && c <= 'F') 
                    ? (uint8_t )(c  - 'A')
                    : 0));
}

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    if (argc == 2)
    {
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i <= 7; i++)
        {
            char *str = argv[1];

            if (str[2*i] == '\0' || str[2*i+1] == '\0')
            {
                printf("Got short string.\n");
                return 1;
            }

            le_long_long_array.byte[i] = (hex2int(str[2*i]) << 4) + hex2int(str[2*i+1]);
        }
        printf("Got %lld\n", le_long_long_array.longlong);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Got %d args wanted 1.\n", argc - 1);
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Produces:

```
e e$ gcc -c un.c
e e$ gcc -o un un.o
e e$ ./un 0100000000000000
Got 1
e e$ ./un 0101000000000000
Got 257
e e$ ./un a23639333301000000
Got 1319414347266
e e$
```

as you would expect for little endian data.

Comment: Keep in mind endianness, but I don't know how big a concern that really is.

Comment: Yes, I used the prefix le_ because the Mac is Little Endian since x86  though in this case the responsibility is really on the user of the structure to fill out the byte array in an endian appropriate manner.

Comment: I tried this, and ended up with the number 866006690. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

```
long long num = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    num = (num << 8) | byte_array[i];
}
```

Assuming they're stored big-endian.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your desired endianness, something like this would work:

```
int i;
char inArray[8] = { 0x00,0x00,0x01,0x33,0x33,0x9e,0x36,0xa2 };
long long outLong = 0;

for(i=0; i<8; i++)
    outLong |= ( (long long)inArray[i]) << (i*8) );
```

Comment: &= is not the right operator here. and the array contains hexadecimal values.

Comment: Yes, I noticed the operator and fixed it. And it appears I misinterpreted the question. Fixing that as well, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Great question! And great answers! To throw in a cent:

```
// Getting stuff "in"
unsigned long long ll1 = 1319420966562;
unsigned char * c = reinterpret_cast<unsigned char *>( &ll1 );

// Getting stuff "out"
unsigned long long ll2;
memcpy( &ll2, c, 8 );
```

`ll2` is now equal to `ll1`.

I must admin, however, I like the `union` examples better. :)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a pointer notation?

```
uint8_t Array[8] = { 0x00,0x00,0x01,0x33,0x33,0x9e,0x36,0xa2 };
uint32_t *Long = Array;
```

Or if possible

```
*((uint32_t*)Array)
```